# Ipad DWG/DXF viewing

Tags: ipad, ios, viewer, dwg, dxf

I have seen applications for iPad that let you view dxf and dwg files.

Does anyone know where to get info on how to do this?  Are there any available tutorials?  I haven't been able to find any.

I really need some direction on how to do this.  The application I'm making just needs to show the files and layers.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

At present RealDwg is not available on iOS platform, so no way to view local dwg/dxf files.

But you have the other option. You create servers which open dwg files and send entities information in some format to your app, then your app can shows them. Through this way, your app can handle extremely large file. See AutoCAD WS.